# Cache a number of responses from external json feeds?

Tags: cache, json, feed

I have a project which displays information from about 60 stock tickers.
The issue is, that the project is making requests every time the page loads for these 60 stocks.

This is kind of how it looks right now:

```
    $elements = array('Stock1', 'Stock2' , 'Stock3', 'Stock4' , 'Stock5',  'Stock6', 'Stock7', 'Stock8', );

foreach ( $elements as $index => $element ) {
    $ticker = $element;

$url = 'https://api.myapi.com/chart?ticker=' . $ticker . '';

$response = wp_remote_get($url, $args);
    $body     = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response );
    $http_code = wp_remote_retrieve_response_code( $response );
    $formatted_json = json_decode($body, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);

} ?>
```

I can't make a combined (for more than 1 stocks information) request from the API at one time. What would be the best way to cache this? The stock information is not in real time (delayed by 15 min), so I guess if I were able to cache results for 5 minutes each time before downloading them again, that would be sufficient. Any tips are appreciated.

Comment: What have you researched so far / how comfortable are you with WordPress development? I think fetching the data [via a Cron](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/) and saving it somewhere in the database (either custom table or options with autoload off) should be enough

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I had some trouble with the CRON method, but I managed to do it with transients. Does the CRON method offer better performance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$body = get_transient( 'my_api_response_value' );

if ( false === $body ) 
{
    $url = 'https://api.myapi.com/chart?ticker=' . $ticker . '';
    $response = wp_remote_get($url);

    if (200 !== wp_remote_retrieve_response_code($response)) {
        return;
    }

    $body = wp_remote_retrieve_body($response);
    set_transient( 'my_api_response_value', $body, 5*MINUTE_IN_SECONDS );
}

$formatted_json = json_decode($body, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

We submit a request at the beginning because the transient doesn't yet exist, and then we save the $body as a transitory value.

More info about the transient go to this Link : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/set_transient/

Comment: +1 but obviously you'll need a different transient per $ticker so you'll need to append that to the name.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to do it like this and loading down is down by 1.5 sec, so thanks a bunch for that!

Comment: If you have a high traffic site, it might make sense to use [WP Redis](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-redis/) or [Redis Object Cache](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redis-cache/), because by default transients are stored in the database, whereas the mentioned plugins offload this to a Redis instance